# Problem with network and how to fix it?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, ethernet, lan

When I try to connect to the network it shows the VPN page settings and doesn't connect to the network.

[image]

[image]

And it doesn't show the Wi-Fi icon in the right corner.

When I connect LAN cable to my laptop, Ubuntu doesn't recognize my cable and the same problem with Wi-Fi above occurs.

Comment: Please open a terminal with CTRL+ALT+T and type in `nmcli network off` and then `nmcli network on`. Does it reconnect?